# What is Perl DBI difference between with bind_columns and without it?

Tags: perl, bind, fetch, dbi

What is the difference between the following code in perl dbi?

1.

```
while (my ($p1, $p2, $p3) = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    # ... some code ...
}
```

2.

```
$sth->bind_columns(\my ($p1, $p2, $p3));
while ($sth->fetch) {
    # ... some code ...
}
```

Both leads to the same result. 
Perlmonks advise on bind variant.
I would appreciate if someone explain why.

Comment: Besides the perfomance difference, the variables have a difference scope. In the first example, they only exist in the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the docs says, that binding is more efficient way to fetch data:

> The binding is performed at a low level using Perl aliasing. Whenever
>   a row is fetched from the database $var_to_bind appears to be
>   automatically updated simply because it now refers to the same memory
>   location as the corresponding column value. This makes using bound
>   variables very efficient.

Comment: if both variants leads to same result, what difference except perfomance it could be?

Comment: The question came from the fact that perlmonks was given only one argument in favor of bind_columns: "you don't need to use that array reference, because you've got the column values bound to Perl variables, and you can just use those directly ... Each time you call fetch on your statement handle, the values of the bound variables get updated." But the first variant does the same thing.

Comment: this is the same meanins, but in other words: if you dont need to use extra assignments, so it causes extra perfomance

Comment: Ok. Thank you for resolving my fears.